# IOs Swift : How does completion closure work

Tags: swift, swift2, closures, completion

Can anybody explain me, how does this code work

```
private func viewWillTransition(completion:(() -> Void)?)
{
    if completion != nil
    {
        completion!()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic scheme of implementing *callbacks* in Swift.

The function takes parameter `completion` of type `() -> Void)?`, meaning "an optional closure taking no parameters and not returning a value."

The code inside tests the optional value of `closure` for `nil`. If it is not `nil`, the code unwraps it with `!`, and makes a call.

A somewhat more idiomatic way of implementing this in Swift is with `if let` construct:

```
private func viewWillTransition(completion:(() -> Void)?) {
    if let nonEmptyCompletion = completion  {
        nonEmptyCompletion()
    }
}
```